# How to fix these warning messages when running VLC player from command-line?

Tags: macos, command-line, audio, vlc-media-player

I installed VLC player on macOS using Homebrew, then when running it from command-line, I got many messages/warnings:

```
% which vlc
/usr/local/bin/vlc
% vlc
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.16-0-g5e70837d8d)
[00007f8476012eb0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
2021-12-25 19:05:48.211 VLC[10273:272753] Can't find app with identifier com.apple.iTunes
2021-12-25 19:05:48.439 VLC[10273:272753] Can't find app with identifier com.spotify.client
[00007f847621e240] auhal audio output error: AudioObjectAddPropertyListener failed, device id 251, prop: [atfp], OSStatus: 1852797029
[00007f847621e240] auhal audio output error: AudioObjectAddPropertyListener failed, device id 239, prop: [atfp], OSStatus: 1852797029
[00007f847621e240] auhal audio output error: AudioObjectAddPropertyListener failed, device id 55, prop: [atfp], OSStatus: 1852797029
[00007f847621e240] auhal audio output error: AudioObjectAddPropertyListener failed, device id 66, prop: [atfp], OSStatus: 1852797029
...
```

And this:

```
% which cvlc
cvlc not found
```

Any idea how to fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the syntax to run VLC play from command-line with an interface specification is to use the `--intf` (or `-I`) option:

vlc --intf <name_of_interface>

where the name of the interface can be chosen from the list given by

```
vlc -l | grep -iF interface
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.16-0-g5e70837d8d)
18:  macosx                 Mac OS X interface
21:  ncurses                Ncurses interface
127:  oldrc                  Remote control interface
140:  lua                    Command-line interface
144:  lua                    Lua Playlist Parser Interface
160:  dummy                  Dummy interface
202:  motion                 motion control interface
353:  hotkeys                Hotkeys management interface
370:  gestures               Mouse gestures control interface
```

For example, to use no interface:

```
vlc -I dummy my_audio.mp3
```

To use textual interface is:

```
vlc -I lua my_audio.mp3
```

The fact

```
vlc my_audio.mp3
```

gives a warning that suggests 'cvlc' seems to be an obsolete command name.